# Layouts for Facebook applications

Tags: css, facebook, fbml

Can anyone point me to multi-column layouts for Facebook canvas applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook apps use the exact same markup as any regular HTML page (HTML is a subset of FBML), so any regular multi-column layout will work just fine.  Just keep in mind that your canvas size is limited to 768px, and adjust any widths accordingly.